# how to write a shell script to know other computer in local network

Tags: shell

I want to write a Bourne shell script that takes a machine name as an argument and displays a message informing you whether the host is on the local network

Comment: how to know ip address from computername? Then compare with my ip to know is the same local network or not?

Comment: We aren't going to do this for you. What have you tried? Are there any linux commands that can tell you this information? Where would machine names be stored on a Linux machine?

Comment: I'm beginer in unix system and i try alot of command to do this (4h search in google). But i can't get the information i want.

Answer (score 0):

ping -c 1 -t 5 a_machine_name >> /dev/null && echo "The machine is on LAN" || echo "The machine is not conencted to LAN"

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Please enter host you would like to ping:
read PING
ping "$PING"
```

Comment: That doesn't tell him if it's on the local network though other than he should be able to figure that out from the IP.

Comment: `traceroute -m 1 "$PING"` I believe will tell you if the IP is on the same subnet.

Comment: @Codeguy: I find link help to determine two ips same subnet: http://www.ehow.com/how_5088467_determine-two-ips-same-subnet.html
So, i write shell script follow this guide.
Anything else more simple?